# Adding a space between uppsercase letters

Tags: string, go

I have string like this `ClientLovesProcess` I need to add a space between each uppercase letter except for the first uppercase letter so the end result would be this `Client Loves Process`

I don't think golang has the best string support but this is how I was thinking about going about it:

First loop through each letter so something like this:

```
name := "ClientLovesProcess"

wordLength := len(name)

for i := 0; i < wordLength; i++ {
    letter := string([]rune(name)[i])

    // then in here I would like to check
   // if the letter is upper or lowercase

   if letter == uppercase{
       // then break the string and add a space
   }
}
```

The issue is I don't know how to check if a letter is lower or uppercase in go. I checked the strings manual but they don't some to have a function for it. What would be another approach to get this done with go?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The function you're looking for is [`unicode.IsUpper(r rune) bool`](https://golang.org/pkg/unicode/#IsUpper).

I would use a `bytes.Buffer` so that you're not doing a bunch of string concatenations, which results in extra unnecessary allocations.

Here's an implementation:

```
func addSpace(s string) string {
    buf := &bytes.Buffer{}
    for i, rune := range s {
        if unicode.IsUpper(rune) && i > 0 {
            buf.WriteRune(' ')
        }
        buf.WriteRune(rune)
    }
    return buf.String()
}
```

And a [play link](https://play.golang.org/p/KVeodOEK8S).

Answer (score 0):

You can test for upper case with the unicode package. This is my solution:

[playground](https://play.golang.org/p/m_LpqTHIMa)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
    "unicode"
)

func main() {
    name := "ClientLovesProcess"
    newName := ""
    for _, c := range name {

        if unicode.IsUpper(c){
            newName += " "   
        }
        newName += string(c)
    }
    newName = strings.TrimSpace(newName) // get rid of space on edges.
    fmt.Println(newName)
}
```